How to change a single value in YAML file via Matlab?
I have the following YAML file description:
messageQueue:
  queue:
    name: "username"          
    create: true            
    durable: false         
    exclusive: false        
    autoDelete: false       
  host: 'localhost'         
  port: 5672

However, I would like to change only the "name" field of the yaml file via MATLAB and then run the file with another pre-built function.
How can I do this ?
Thanks,
Dhruv

You could use regular expressions to find the name: line, replace the string, and reconstruct the yml. This should only be used if your yaml isn't too complex, otherwise you'll have an increasingly difficult set of edge cases to handle...
I've added comments to the below code to explain each step, including the logic for my regex pattern
% read in the entire yml as a char
yml = fileread('test.yml');
% define the new name to replace in the name field
newName = 'test';

% Find the start and end indicies in the char for the line following the pattern:
%  ^\s+    start of line, then one or more spaces
%  name:   then the keyword `name:`
%  \s*     then zero or more spaces
%  ".+"    then one or more of any characters surrounded by double quotes
[a,b] = regexp( yml, '^\s+name:\s*".+"', 'once', 'lineanchors');
% Make new line by replacing the bit after the colon with the new name in quotes
name = sprintf('%s: "%s"', extractBefore(yml(a:b),':'), newName );
% Reconstruct the yml string from before and after then name line, 
% with the modified name line in the middle
yml = [yml(1:a-1), name, yml(b+1:end)];

% Write to a new file
fid = fopen( 'testModified.yml', 'w' );
fprintf( fid, yml );
fclose( fid );

Perhaps an easier way is to invent some unique syntax for variables to replace, and use that instead of faffing around with regex, for example if your original yaml was this:
messageQueue:
  queue:
    name: "$$USERNAME$$"          
    create: true            
    durable: false

Then you could just have the MATLAB code
yml = fileread('test.yml');
newName = 'test';
yml = strrep( yml, '$$USERNAME$$', newName );

Before writing back to a file in the same way (fopen/fprintf/fclose).

Thank you so much for your answer. I think what I need is increasing the complexity with this approach. Is there a way I can have a variable from Matlab inside the file and it gets updated directly inside the file.

@dhruvguptadg I don't know what you mean by it getting updated "directly inside the file". This answer modifies the yaml contents and writes it to a new file. You could edit the fopen line to write back to the original file instead if you want. I've added a different approach to my answer in case that's more what you were imagining

Yes, I can use this as well. However, is it possible to append the same file with the changed word/line ?

I am able to change the username inside the file and rewrite it to the same file. However, now that the yaml file is changed with username -> "xyz", now if I want to change the name to something else(value stored in a variable) then how can I proceed ?

The code above doesn't look for "username", it looks for anything inside double quotes after name:, as described in my code comments. So it shouldn't matter.

I tried your code, but the indices a and b remain blank when I run the regexp line.
str = 'name:"username"'
[a,b] = regexp( str, '^\s+name:\s*".+"', 'once', 'lineanchors');

That's because you have no whitespace in the test str used there before name, whereas in the example of your question name is indented at least twice. I used ^\s+ in the regex to enforce spaces between the start of the line and name: to avoid matching the work name anywhere else in the yaml. Please see the detailed comments for a description of what the regex is expecting

it works perfectly fine now. One more thing: what if there is no quotes ahead of name:username then how can this be done ?

Remove the " quotes from the regex pattern, please see the matlab docs or a regex checker site like http://regex101.com. Consider marking this answer as "accepted" with the green tick mark by the voting buttons if the question is resolved.
